# What Goes Wrong in the Application of Lax-Milgram?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have the following equation

$$\int\nabla u\nabla v =\int fv$$

So I want to find $f$ for which there is an unique $u$ so the above is satisfied for all $v$ in the space (say $H^1$).

So define bilinear map $B$ from $H^1$ to $\mathbb R$
$$B(u,v):=\int\nabla u \nabla v$$
Clearly by Cauchy-Schwartz and Poincare inequalitites
$$B(u,v)\leq C||u||||v||$$

$$B(u,u) \geq C||u||^2$$

So now by Lax-Milgram for any functional $f$ there exists $u_f$, so that for all $v$

$$B(u_f,v)=(f,v)$$

So we should be done by Riesz representation, choosing any $f$ on $H^1$. However, if we choose $f=1$ we find that when $v=1$ regardless of $u$ we get $$\int\nabla u\nabla v=0=\int f \neq 0 $$

So this should only work when the integral of $f$ is zero. What went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used the Poincaré inequality, but this only holds (in this form) on suitable subspaces of $H^1$. For example, it is wrong for $u=1$.